# Android - get phone number from incoming call - Playstore App rejected

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-phone-call

In my application I implemented a feature to get a phone number from incoming call and it is working fine previously. But after android 9 to proceed further we need to add permission read call log in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

But after add these the app got rejected due to this (READ_CALL_LOG) permission added in manifest file. Playstore inform that the these functionality as a core in the application then only they will accept it. But this functionality is not a core one and it is part of my app.

Can anybody have any idea about this and how to proceed further?

Comment: What else does PlayStore say? What's their suggestion? do they need you to remove it? Why?

Comment: They are asking to remove it